# Order of initialization/instantiation of class variables of derived class and invoking of base class constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, initialization, instantiation

I want to figure out the order of 1) initialization/instatiation of derived class variables 2) invoking of base class constructor in this code snippet

```
public class base 
{
  int y = 1;
  public base()
  { 
      y = 2; 
      function();
  }
  void function () 
  {
     System.out.println("In base Value = " + String.valueOf(y));
  }

  public static class derived extends base 
  {
      int y = 3;
      public derived()
      { 
          function();
      }
      void function () 
      {
          System.out.println("In derived Value = " + String.valueOf(y));
      }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  { 
      base b = new base.derived();
      return;
  }
}
```

my understadning is that first, derived class is instatiated, then base class constructor is called, then derived class variables y is initialized. Is this order correct?

Comment: Base class is always instantiated first, then initializers, then the constructor. Note that your two `y` fields are not the same field, so first call to `function` prints 0 (derived.y not yet initialized), and second call prints 3.

Comment: So, is the base class constructor is called before y in B is initialized to 3?

Comment: But in your comment  "then initializers, then the constructor" is written. Doesn't it imply y in b is intialized first? I got confused here please calrify

Comment: Base class **first** (`base` initializers, then `base` constructor), *then* subclass (`derived` initializers, then `derived` constructor).

Comment: Thanks @Andreas. Can you please tell me about the order of instantiation of the objects as well? My understanding is subclass derived is instantiated first, then Base class base is instantiated, and then the order is same as the one you mentioned in your previous comment. Is that correct?

Comment: No idea what you are asking since the entire discussion so far has been about object instantiation.

Answer (score 3):

The order of execution occurs in the following manner:

1) Static initializers

[Base class instantiation]

2) Instance initializers

3) The constructor

4) The remainder of the main.

Static initialisers precede base class instantiation.

If you have more than 1 instance initialiser they occur in the order they are written in from top to bottom.

---

### Your code

You do not have any instance blocks.

The parent class constructor runs first, the y variable with in the base class is set to 2, the function method is then called, however the function method has been overridden in the subclass, hence the subclass method is used.

However the derived.y variable has not yet been initialized, hence the value of y is defaulted to 0.

After that occurs, the sub-class; derived's constructor then runs, the value of derived.y is declared as 3 and the override function method defined in the derived class runs, hence printing the derived value is 3.

Note: The two y variables are not the same.

Comment: @Pavan_k_k do you fully understand or is there any parts that you would like me to explain in more detail?

Comment: Sorry, just a bit confused. You wrote `Instance initializers` executed before `The constructor` but then you wrote `The parent class constructor runs first, the y variable with in the base class is set to 2`, but isn't that order opposite?

Answer (score 0):

To add to the conversation (and this is in Kotlin which is similar to Java), the output of the following program

```
open class Base {

    val x = 1

    constructor() {
        println("x=$x")
        function()
    }

    open fun function() {

    }

    open class Derived1 : Base {

        val y = 2

        constructor() {
            println("y=$y")
            function()
        }

        override fun function() {
            println("In derived Value = $y")
        }
    }

    class Derived2 : Derived1 {

        var z = 3

        constructor() : super() {
            println("z=$z")
            function()
        }

        override fun function() {
            println("In derived Value = $z")
        }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val b: Base = Base.Derived2()
    return
}
```

is

```
x=1
In derived Value = 0
y=2
In derived Value = 0
z=3
In derived Value = 3

Process finished with exit code 0
```